# Angular Reactive Form - Options dropdown menu

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

Is there a way to display form values from an Observable using the reactive approach? I have a form with hard-coded data for this example and it displays my list of Labels in the HTML, but I am facing two issues I hope someone can spot that I'm not seeing/understanding.

1. There is a TypeError: Cannot read property 'label' of undefined when using this.labels$[0].label as the initial form value for the field. I was hoping it would pull in the first label from my labels$() list.
2. If I change the above to a string e.g. 'Test', the dropdown menu renders and I get the following

> `{"labels": "Test", "field1": "Some value", "field2": "Some value" }` 
>   but when I change the dropdown menu, it removes the labels value completely.
>
> `{"field1": "Some value", "field2": "Some value" }`

TS

```
get labels$() {
  return [
        { "label": "label-1" }, // e.g. Mr.
        { "label": "label-2" },
        { "label": "label-3" },
        { "label": "label-4" }
      ];
}
```

HTML

```
<rx-select formControlName="labels" [options]="labels$ | async" [label]="Label"></rx-select>
```

Component.ts

```
return new FormGroup({
          labels: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
          field1: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
          field2: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
        });
```

Form

The ideal form value would be the following where I could see the values change with my interaction.

`{"labels": "label-1", "field1": "Some value", "field2": "Some value" }`

Any advice appreciated as I navigate the reactive form experience ;)

Comment: By convention, suffixing a variable with '$' is done when this variable is an Observable. It seems that it should be an observable, since you're using `labels$ | async`. But it's not: it's an array. You also use the name `labels`, with a final `s`, to reference a single label. Very confusing again. Fix those errors, and post a complete minimal example as a stackblitz, explaining what you're doing, what you expect to happen, and what happens instead.

Comment: what is rx-select??

Comment: @Eliseo - rx-select is a directive.

Comment: @JBNizet - yes $ is associated with an Observable but for this example, the data was hardcoded array which is what my observable object is when complete. As for labels, it is as is. i.e. a list of labels! Tnx

Answer (score 1):

If you want to just view the value of a FormGroup, then you can do it in 2 ways:

1. Print the value for FormGroup instance in the **HTML**, with `async` pipe. `json` pipe is needed to format the object into text.

*In the HTML file:*

```
formGroupInstance.valueChanges | async | json
```

2. Print the value for FormGroup instance in the **Console**, by subscribing to the 
   `valueChanges`.

*In the TypeScript File:*

```
formGroupInstance.valueChanges.subscribe(value => console.log(value));
```

You can find an example [HERE | stackblitz.com](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yw7qdd)

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue. The json object needs a value in order to render correctly in the directive dropdown. So changing { "label": "label-1" } to { "label": "label-1", "value": "value1" } works.